# Real time rate and pitch adjustments Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, avspeechsynthesizer

I am setting up a tts app with `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. I have to do real-time pitch and rate adjustments. I am using `UISLider` for adjusting pitch and rate.

Here is my code:-

```
@IBAction func sl(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if synthesizer.isSpeaking {
        synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)

        self.rate = sender.value

        if currentRange.length > 0 {
            let valuee = currentRange.length + currentRange.location
            let neww = self.tvEditor.text.dropFirst(valuee)
            self.tvEditor.text = String(neww)
            synthesizer.speak(buildUtterance(for: rate, pitch: pitch, with: String(neww), language: self.preferredVoiceLanguageCode2 ?? "en"))
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have understood your problem even if no details are provided: **you can't take into account the new values** of the `rate` and `pitchMultiplier` **when the speech is running**.

To explain the following details, I read [this example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) that contains code snippets *(ObjC, Swift)* and illustrations.
[image]

1. Create your `AVSpeechUtterance` instances with their `rate` and `pitchMultiplier` properties.
2. Add each one of them in an array that will represent the queue to be spoken.
3. Make a loop inside the previous queue with the synthesizer to read out every elements.

Now, **if you want to change the property values in real-time**, see the steps hereafter once one of your sliders moves:

4. Get the current spoken utterance thanks to the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol.
5. Run the `stopSpeaking` synthesizer method that will remove from the queue the utterances that haven't been spoken yet.
6. Create the previous removed utterances with the new property values.
7. Redo steps 2/ and 3/ to resume where you stopped with these updated values.

The synthesizer queues all information to be spoken long before you ask for new values that don't impact the stored utterances: **you must remove and recreate the utterances with their new property values** to be spoken.

If the code example provided by the link above isn't enough, I suggest to take a look at [this WWDC video detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html) dealing with `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.